# Is there a dictionary-like datastructure that would allow searches for 'key' and for 'value'

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

I need a structure for my little Python program to save a list **of max 500** names with one number each. The names would be unique, but the numbers would repeat (often). I first thought of a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping), but I also need to be able to search for the numbers, for instance I would need to change all `2` to `3`. What would you recommend?

I am new to Python, so I am sure I overlooked a simple solution.

```
("Spiderman",1)
("Dr. House",2)
("Jon Skeet",1)
```

Comment: You could also couple two dicts if both directions have to be constant time.

Comment: hi, I will only save like 500 names at max. So a database would be overkill imho.

Comment: 500 names are so few that a dictionary and linear search of the values should be adequate for your described use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dict, and search by value like so:

```
names = {"Spiderman":1, "Dr. House":2, "Jon Skeet":1}

resulting_keys = [k for k, v in names.iteritems() if v == 1]
# returns ['Spiderman', 'Jon Skeet']
```

Then you can do something like:

```
 names.update(dict((k,names[k] + 1) for k in resulting_keys))
```

Which will now update names to:

```
{'Jon Skeet': 2, 'Dr. House': 2, 'Spiderman': 2}
```

Comment: Please tell me if I am wrong, but the line [k for k, v in names.iteritems() if v == 1] seems to me the proper way to do it in Python in contrast to a for-loop?

Comment: List comprehension, when used in the right context, is more Pythonic.

Comment: List comprehensions seem to be the right way to do it in most cases; the exception being if you are doing output, mutating a value, or otherwise "pushing" data.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary would work.  If you need to change the stored values:

```
>>> d = {"SpiderMan":1, "Dr.House":2, "Jon Skeet":1}
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     if v == 1:
...         d[k] = v+1
...         
...     
... 
>>> d
{'SpiderMan': 2, 'Dr.House': 2, 'Jon Skeet': 2}
```

It's going to be a linear search (O(n)).  Do you need better than that?